# In what language was Loki talking to the people of Pompeii?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, loki-2021

In the *Loki* TV series,

> Loki tried to cause time variance in Pompeii to prove his point. He told people of Pompeii that they were all going to die in a language I couldn't understand.
>
>  [image]

What language was that?

Comment: I've downvoted this because even the most cursory of searches would have revealed the answer to you instantly.

Comment: What's especially odd is that the photo in this question has been copied from an answer on Quora about the language that Loki was speaking; https://itsallmarvel.quora.com/https-www-quora-com-In-what-language-was-Loki-talking-in-with-the-people-of-Pompeii-in-the-series-Loki-episode-2-answe

Comment: On the other hand, at least three languages were spoken in ancient Pompeii -- Greek, Latin, and Oscan.

Comment: For the record, in the most recent episode the subtitles indicate that he's singing in Asgardian.

Comment: This is also trivially answered (as Valorum's answer indicates) by *turning on the Disney+ subtitles*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's Latin.

Note that Loki and Mobius were in Pompeii in 79 AD, [at which time, Latin was the predominant language in that region](https://www.britannica.com/place/Pompeii).

Also, the first sentence he speaks in the scene in question is...

> Mihi nomen est Loki.

... which translates from Latin to English as "My name is Loki."

And, for what it's worth, Hiddleston majored in [Classics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classics) (Latin and Classical Greek) at the University of Cambridge.

Comment: Given that he's not listed as a writer for the show, I'm not sure why the fact that he *speaks* Latin is especially relevant.

Comment: It doesn't prove he was speaking Latin, but I wouldn't consider the actor's established ability to speak the language as being irrelevant to the question. I'd say it falls into the category of indirect evidence, proving that he's unusually well qualified to perform such a scene, and is certainly worth noting in relation to the question.

Comment: Also, while Hiddleston isn't listed as a _writer_ on the show, he is credited as an executive producer, so I imagine he has some say on what happens on the show.

Comment: @Valorum anyone with even a basic understanding of Latin can tell you that was Latin, even without the obvious contextual clue

Comment: @OrangeDog - as I said in another comment, that should make incredibly easy for them to find and present some evidence to back up their claims. I'm not suggesting that they're wrong, but *"because I say so"* is insufficient proof for my liking.

Comment: @Valorum much like on a previous question, a dictionary should suffice

Comment: @OrangeDog - Sure, or in this case, they've added some of the wording and demonstrated that it's actually Latin instead of just saying "it's latin" and expecting us to take them at their word. What if the next person comes along and says "It's not Latin". Are we expected to take them at their word also?

Comment: Funny thing is, Loki's Latin is a bit incorrect, as far as I noticed. When Loki goes "Atque adferro acerbum nuncium ad vos omnes" (and I bear bitter news to you all) the last two words should be "vobis omnibus" - at least I think they should - since they are in the object of a prepositional phrase (ad vobis omnes = to you all) and thus should be in the ablative case.

Comment: @calc-you-later that's an interesting question for the Latin Stack Exchange. The usual construction at that time would put it in the dative case (indirect object), which is indeed *vobis omnibus* or *omnibus vobis*. (Word order is irrelevant to meaning in this case.) Much later in Latin, prepositions began to take on a much more prominent role, and the usual construction would have used *ad* ("to"), which takes the accusative case: *ad vos omnes/omnes vos* (the latteris possible but doesn't feel right to me).

Comment: ahh I see, I think that makes sense. I remember some cases when "ad" did end up taking the accusative case in some translations I had to do for class, so you could be right there. I'll do some more research and post a question the Latin Stack Exchange should I come up empty-handed. Thanks!

Comment: Dang! Here I was thinking it was Italian... :/

Answer (score 3):

Latin (with a very English/Cambridge accent).

Comment: I've downvoted this. Although it's not incorrect, a decent answer would offer some evidence to back it up.

Comment: @Valorum Evidence!?! What language am I writing in right now? Do you think it’s English? What evidence do you have to back that up? I’m assuming you know it’s English because you can read and write English. Well I can understand (a bit of) Latin, as can many other people. If you took Latin in school, it’s painfully obvious that Lok is speaking Latin. What evidence would one present? It’s like “provide evidence that this color is blue”. Ummm… just look at it.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - In which case it should be *incredibly easy for you to find and present some evidence.*

Comment: You might quote a bit of what Loki said.

Comment: Someone who is colour-blind might want more evidence of blueness than "*because I told you so*"

Answer (score 3):

*Uno valet imago mille verba* (One picture is worth a thousand words)

[image]

The official Disney+ subtitles confirm what language he's speaking.